# Placing 0 in a FOR loop returns unwanted result

Tags: javascript

I started to learn JavaScript, so far enjoying it.
I have this loop (the purpose is to fined the highest number inside an array):

```
function max(arr) {
  var max = arr[0]; 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
    return max;
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work, unless I change i to i = 1. Can someone explain why? Thanks!

Comment: your `return max;` is inside the `for` loop - it should be outside it

Comment: Probably the highest number is at position 1, and as the loops terminates at the first iteration, itll return the right value by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

In your implementation attempt, you have a logical error:

```
function max(arr) {
  var max = arr[0]; 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
    // return max; <-- this always returns arr[0]
  }
  return max; // <-- it should be here to work as expected
}
```

Another improvement would be to start at `var i = 1` since you've already assigned the initial value of `arr[0]` to `max` before starting the for loop.

But below is a much better and more robust implementation.

#### Solution

Technically, you should be doing this to account for empty arrays, arrays with negative values, malformed values, or values that are coercible to valid numbers:

```
function myMax(array) {
  var max = -Infinity

  for (var index = 0, value; index < array.length; index++) {
    // coerce element to number
    value = Number(array[index])
    // short-circuit for malformed value
    if (isNaN(value)) return value
    if (value > max) max = value
  }

  return max
}
```

#### Matches ECMAScript Specification of `Math.max()`

This is functionally equivalent to the following implementation for all possible array inputs, empty or non-empty:

```
function max(array) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, array)
}
```

From the [documentation for `Math.max()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Return_value):

> If no arguments are given, the result is `-Infinity`.
>
> If at least one of arguments cannot be converted to a number, the result is `NaN`.

#### Demo

```js
function myMax(array) {
  var max = -Infinity

  for (var index = 0, value; index < array.length; index++) {
    // coerce element to number
    value = Number(array[index])
    // short-circuit for malformed value
    if (isNaN(value)) return value
    if (value > max) max = value
  }

  return max
}

function specMax(array) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, array)
}

function test(input) {
  var set = new Set()
  console.log('input:', JSON.stringify(input))
  set.add(myMax(input))
  console.log('output:', myMax(input), '[myMax(input)', set.has(specMax(input)) ? 'matches' : 'does not match', 'specMax(input)]')
}

test([-50, 25, 0, 50, -25])
test([-100, -80, -90, -85, -95])
test([])
test([0, 'malformed', 100, 20])
test([1, 2, 3, 4, ' 5.e0  \t\r\n'])
test([{
  toString () { return '200' },
  valueOf () { return 100 },
  toJSON () {
    return {
      "toString()": this.toString(),
      "valueOf()": this.valueOf()
    }
  }
}])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Returns -Infinity for an empty array. I would argue that is incorrect as the array is empty, not an array with a -Infinity element.

Comment: @manassehkatz as I said, that is by design, and follows the JavaScript specification for [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Return_value)

Comment: That is the behavior of Math.max() - but is that what OP wants? (Admittedly, I would just Math.max myself once I saw it was available.)

Comment: @manassehkatz the solution adheres to the design pattern used by OP while abiding to the specification. I'd heavily consider removing the downvote, as this is the most correct answer here.

Comment: Removing the downvote as you make a valid point in the comparison to Math.max. But I still think my answer is the most correct. Let the OP decide!

Comment: Thanks for the informative comment! I will look into it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts And the OP likes your answer better after all.

Comment: @manassehkatz probably because I'm the only one that actually answered their original question :P

Answer (score 0):

```
function max(arr) {
  var max = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (Math.max(arr[i], max) == arr[i]) {
      max = arr[i];
   }
  }
  return max;

}
```

If you make a return instruction in a for loop, it break it.

Comment: Correct about return, but indexing is wrong. Actually not so sure (I undid my downvote while I figure this out)

Comment: Still doesn't work, it returns the first value of the array (like before)

Comment: If i post it, it's because i tried it and it work :) Show us your array

Comment: @Superdrac This will give an incorrect answer if all arr values are negative.

Comment: Thanks! it did work. my computer acted extremely weird for some reason,  had to create a new file and link it to the html in order for this to work, no idea why. tanks again

Answer (score 0):

Moving the return is necessary. But with i=1 you never see the first element of the array.

```
function max(arr) {
   var max; 
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if ((max !== undefined) && (arr[i] > max)) {
         max = arr[i];
      }
   }
   return max;
}
```

This will even return the perhaps unexpected but arguably correct value of undefined if arr is empty.